# Symlinked files giving errors in vite

Tags: laravel, vite, inertiajs

*EDIT*: I've created a docker image with a skeleton project to demonstrate my issue: praisedare/vite-symlinked-file-error. I've included the instructions to setup the docker environment at the bottom of the question.

---

This is the directory structure of my project:

```
resources
|-+ js/
|---+ components/
|---+ tenant/
|-----+ Pages/
|-----+ components/
|-----+ composables/
|-----+ app.js
|-+ views/
```

I'm trying to use a symlink for the `resources/js/tenant` directory in my laravel/vite project. When I load any page that uses vue files from that symlinked directory, I get this error: `The specifier “vue (or any other import first encountered)” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.`. But the moment I delete the symlink and copy-paste the folder, everything starts to work just fine.

In case you're wondering why I'm doing this instead of just going the normal route and using the real folder, it's due to the constraints of the project I'm currently working on. The `tenant` files are used by different versions of the project, which must all have the same code for that `tenant` directory. I could choose to use an actual folder instead of symlinking it, but then I'd have to copy-paste any changes I make across the different versions of the project.

This is the main `app.js` file:

```js
import './bootstrap.js';
import '../../css/app.css';

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import VueHtmlToPaper from 'vue-html-to-paper';
import VueApexCharts from "vue3-apexcharts";

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .use(pinia)
            .use(VueHtmlToPaper, printerSetup)
            .use(VueApexCharts)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#FFA500',
    },
});
```

To reproduce, you can take any vite project you have and use a symlink for the folder you're keeping your view (react, vue, e.t.c) files in, and you should get the same error.

---

## Docker environment setup:

To get started:

```bash
docker pull praisedare/vite-symlinked-file-error
docker container run -it --name vite_so_question_demo -p"8000:8000" -p"5173:5173" praisedare/vite-symlinked-file-error bash

# Go to project dir
cd /var/www/laravel-vite-so-question

# Start the server
./server.sh

# I've already installed tmux for your convenience, so you can use it
# to open another tab and explore the project while the server is running
# or you can run the server script as a background process with:
./server.sh &
# and later kill it with
./kill-server.sh

# ps: vim is also installed
```

Then visit [localhost:8000/vite](http://locahost:8000/vite) in your browser, open your console and you should see an error similar to the one I mentioned (`he specifier “vue ” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.`